# Compute odd sum of each given list of numbers

Tags: python, list

How do I determine the sum of all odd positive integers up to some number `arr[i]`. If queries are `arr=[4,5]`, the answers are `1+3=4` for `arr[0]=4` and `1+3+5=9` for `arr[i]=5`.

Comment: What did you try and what is not working with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a naive implementation that uses a `range(..)` and then sums it up, like:

```
def f(n):
    return sum(range(1, n+1, 2))
```

but this runs in *O(n)* if we consider adding numbers together a constant operation.

This is however an [*arithmetic series* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum). If *k* is *k=⌊(n-1)/2⌋*, then this is equal to:

```
 k
---
\              (k+1) (2*k+2)        2
/    2*i + 1 = ------------- = (k+1)
---                 2            
i=0
```

So we can simply calculate this as:

```
def f(n):
    k1 = (n+1) // 2
    return k1 * k1
```

For example:

```
>>> f(4)  # 1 + 3
4
>>> f(5)  # 1 + 3 + 5
9
>>> f(10) # 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9
25
>>> f(123456789)
3810394749276025
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't very clear why would you need to define the list `arr=[4,5]`.

This simple lambda will accomplish your task given an arbitrary positive number:

```py
sum_odd_numbers = lambda num: sum(xrange(1, num + 1, 2))

# Examples
>>> lst = [4, 5]

>>> print sum_odd_numbers(lst[0])
# 4

>>> print sum_odd_numbers(lst[1])
# 9
```

Comment: Please don't solve other people's homework. It will only attract more *low quality* questions.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well, this is a questions and answers forum. In addition, I didn't write a whole script for him just one line, thus this is not close to a complete solution. Also, people that are new to programming can learn a lot from examples.

Comment: I found it useful, I just learned about xrange.  I had to look it up here:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-vs-xrange-python/ ( basically xrange, python3 only, provides an iterator instead of a list object, so it is less of a memory hog ).   Nonethless, I see Willem's point - though in this case it worked out well for me. Also, I liked the use of lamda, I probably would have just written a function.  All in all, an elegant solution.

Comment: @Mark Well actually, `xrange` does not exist in python 3 anymore. Instead, python 3 embraced the the memory improvements by using iterators over complete lists. And so `range` in python 3 is actually what used to be `xrange` in python 2

Comment: @Mark here's a reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges

Comment: @ch0wner - thanks for the correction - I do appreciate it.